# How to pass and refer multiple sideinputs to a DoFn in JAVA

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to figure out how I can pass multiple side inputs to my DoFn and refer them separately inside ProcessContext.

I wasn't able to find anything for this in the beam documentation and wanted to gain some idea on how I can achieve this in JAVA

Answer (score 0):

Though the example of [using side inputs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#side-inputs) only has a single side input, the  same pattern holds for multiple side inputs.
Specifically, the [withSideInputs](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.33.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/ParDo.SingleOutput.html#withSideInputs-org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollectionView...-) method of [ParDo](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.33.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/ParDo.html) takes any number of `PCollectionView`s, each of which can be used as its own key in `ProcessContext.sideInput`.